# Azure CommunicationService - Not being able to receive the SMS

Tags: .net, azure-communication-services

I'm using Azure Communication Service to send SMS through a Web API, after the service is called I receive a 202 response, but the message is never received from phone

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the 202 returned by the service, indicate that your message has been queued to be sent and not delivered. Please review/follow this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/sms/handle-sms-events) to subscribe to delivery report events and troubleshoot.
Once the events are configured, inspect the "**deliveryStatus**" field of your delivery report to verify delivery success/failure.

Also, please review the limits in sending messages/[ref SMS FAQ doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/communication-services/concepts/sms/sms-faq#i-received-a-http-status-202-from-the-send-sms-api-but-the-sms-didnt-reach-my-phone-what-do-i-do-now).

Comment: Thanks. After reading a little bit it turned out the service is only available for USA phone numbers and I never received the SMS. I tried with US numbers and I could receive the messages. Although, I received the same response in both cases (202)

Comment: It's amazing how easy it is to diagnose some services, yet for the SMS you have to jump through a million hoops to understand the SMS process...  I get that it's buried but holy ramp-up time. I haven't worked with EventGrids yet and it's frustrating.